# Geotag shapefiles

Tags: qgis, geotag

I have several shapefiles that are supposed to be in epsg:4326 but the projection is correct only relative to each other, not absolutely.

Is there a way I can geotag shapefiles without having a geotagged picture file.

In QGIS for example?

Comment: I'd be happy if I just knew how to change the coordinates of a single point of a vector and then adjust all the other points relative to it.

Comment: You might look for Affine Transformation or Vector Bender plugin.

Comment: "...the projection is correct only relative to each other, not absolutely". This is kinda the definition of when the projection is **not** correct, rather that you have data with arbitrary coordinates. Is there any chance that you can find out which coordinate system it really is in? Tip: use www.projfinder.com (or ask whoever gave you the data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what you describe simply sounds like the files are **not** in the projection you think. Run ogrinfo to find out what projection they are reporting, if it is a different projection, then you are ok and can simply reproject the data to 4326. If it reports 4326 then your files could be corrupted and you need to go back to your source to find out the true projection if possible